# HP Laserjet waking up randomly

Tags: printer, hp-laserjet

Has anyone ever seen an instance where a printer (in this case a HP Laserjet 500 colorMFP M570dn) wakes up randomly even though no print job is being sent to it?  I'd like to make it stop this.

Comment: Have you contacted HP about this problem?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about "Auto-Off/Auto-On" (energy settings are set to wake from "network only"), if you post the data from the bottom of the left hand column of the network configuration page that is under the "Last Wake:" heading, I can tell you what awoke it the last time. It might be a good idea to grab/post a small sample of them in case there are a few things going on...

Answer (score 1):

Your computer (or a computer on the network if it is shared or networked) may be polling it for connectivity or status. It must wake up in order to respond which may cause it to begin re-heating the fuser or other magic

If you have the only computer which can connect to it, try setting it to "offline mode" in your printer/device settings and see if it stops exhibiting this behavior.

Alternatively, as a test, leave it on but unplug any network or usb cable connected to the printer and see if it still wakes up on its own. (if it has wifi built in, you want to disable this for the test as well)